# How to Connect to an LDAP Server and how to validate AD Groups in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap

I have a Spring Boot application.

I want to connect to an LDAP server and query for valid AD groups.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familiar with Spring Security. Write a configuration class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and configure AD authentication provider.  Refer below code. Change antMatchers to match your app.
Add dependencies spring-security-ldap,spring-boot-starter-security as well.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AppConstants.LOGIN_URI).fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        String ldapUrl = env.getProperty(AppConstants.LDAP_URL);
        String ldapDomain = env.getProperty(AppConstants.LDAP_DOMAIN);
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain,
                ldapUrl);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
```

To get the groups to which user is assigned inject instance of Authentication/Principal in controller class. Get 
To get all attributes against the user like email, manager etc. you may will need to write a custom mapper though. Refer code below.

```
@GetMapping(value = { AppConstants.REST_API_LOGIN })
    public ResponseEntity<User> authenticateUser(Authentication auth) {
        List<String> ldapRoles = new ArrayList<String>();
        auth.getAuthorities().forEach(a -> ldapRoles.add(a.getAuthority()));
/*
Write service class methods to compare ldapRoles against app specific roles from DB and exception handlers to handle exceptions
*/
    User user = userService.getUser(auth);
    if (!user.isAuthorized()) {
        logger.info("User:" + auth.getName() + " is not authorized to access program.");
        throw new UserAuthenticationException(AppConstants.NOT_VALID_MEMBER, user);
    }
    logger.info("User:" + auth.getName() + " logged in");
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```